# Excel - Macro to run keyboard shortcut for VOIP software

Tags: excel, vba, voip, sendkeys

I have an excel spreadsheet with a list of 100 telephone numbers.

I use VOIP software on my PC to make calls and a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>,<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will automatically place a call. The VOIP software takes the telephone number from my spreadsheet using what ever cell I have selected.

I would like to make a "CALL" button in excel so when a cell is hi-lighted & the call button is pressed a macro runs <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Any help or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`Application.SendKeys ("^+C")`